# pandas value_counts() and keep it

Tags: pandas

I want to count the value with .value_counts() and keep it.
for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'fruit':['apples']*3  + ['peaches']*5 + ['bananas']*3 +
                            ['carrots']*4 + ['apricots']*10 })

print (df)

    fruit
0   apples
1   apples
2   apples
3   peaches
4   peaches

df["fruit"].value_counts()

apricots    10
peaches      5
carrots      4
apples       3
bananas      3
Name: fruit, dtype: int64
```

and I want to align the values like,

```
print(df)

    fruit
0   apricots
1   apricots
2   apricots
3   apricots
4   apricots
```

How can I do that??

plz, give me some your idea 
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by align the values, and then there's a series of apricots? I'm confused what that has to do with using `value_counts()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `groupby` and `transform` to make it in one sentence.

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('fruit')['fruit'].transform('count')
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: make value counts table

```
vc = df['fruit'].value_counts().reset_index()
      index  fruit
0  apricots     10
1   peaches      5
2   carrots      4
3    apples      3
4   bananas      3
```

Step 2: Merging

```
f = df.merge(vc, how='left', left_on='fruit', right_on='index')
     fruit_x     index  fruit_y
0     apples    apples        3
1     apples    apples        3
2     apples    apples        3
3    peaches   peaches        5
4    peaches   peaches        5
5    peaches   peaches        5
6    peaches   peaches        5
7    peaches   peaches        5
8    bananas   bananas        3
9    bananas   bananas        3
10   bananas   bananas        3
11   carrots   carrots        4
12   carrots   carrots        4
13   carrots   carrots        4
14   carrots   carrots        4
15  apricots  apricots       10
16  apricots  apricots       10
17  apricots  apricots       10
18  apricots  apricots       10
19  apricots  apricots       10
20  apricots  apricots       10
21  apricots  apricots       10
22  apricots  apricots       10
23  apricots  apricots       10
24  apricots  apricots       10
```

Step 3: Some clean-up

```
f = f.drop('index', axis=1).rename({'fruit_x': 'fruit', 'fruit_y': 'count'}, axis=1)
       fruit  count
0     apples      3
1     apples      3
2     apples      3
3    peaches      5
4    peaches      5
5    peaches      5
6    peaches      5
7    peaches      5
8    bananas      3
9    bananas      3
10   bananas      3
11   carrots      4
12   carrots      4
13   carrots      4
14   carrots      4
15  apricots     10
16  apricots     10
17  apricots     10
18  apricots     10
19  apricots     10
20  apricots     10
21  apricots     10
22  apricots     10
23  apricots     10
24  apricots     10
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!. have a lovely day

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use `pandas.Series.value_counts` with `pd.Index.repeat`:

```
s = df["fruit"].value_counts()
df["fruit"] = s.index.repeat(s)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       fruit
0   apricots
1   apricots
2   apricots
3   apricots
...
21   bananas
22    apples
23    apples
24    apples
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!. have a lovely day